# PIC12F683 or PIC16F688 assembly or C blinking LED example with XC8 compiler, MPASM or gputils

Tags: pic, c, microchip, assembly, xc8

Hello I am new to PIC programming and I finally have got my dev environment working, I downloaded the XC8 compiler from microchip and also as backup I downloaded the gputils assembler. I have not been able to get anything compiled/running and I would appreciate an example. If someone could write a small program demonstrating how to set the config bits and the crystal frequency in either assembly to assemcle it with MPASM or gputils or C to compile with XC8 I would appreciate it. I have a PIC12F683 and a PIC16F688 although for this example I dont think much platform specific stuff maters. Anyways I gave it a shot and here is what I got, but it is not working. Thank you

```
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCCLK // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: 

CLKOUT function on RA4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA5/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Function Select bit (MCLR pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown Out Detect (BOR disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal External Switchover bit (Internal External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)


#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
//INCLUDES
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main(void) {
 GPIO = 0x00;
 ANSEL = 0x00;
 TRISIO = 0x00;
 ADCON0 = 0x00;
 CMCON0 = 7;
    while(1)
    {
        GP0 = 1;
//dont know which delay function to use
        GP0 = 0;

    }
```

Comment: Where is your program?

Comment: posted my program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from missing the end bracket (copy/paste missed the last character?) your code works for me. However there are a couple of omissions that might make you think it doesn't:-

1. `#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000` tells the compiler what frequency the PIC *should* be running at, but does not actually set it. On start up the 12F683 runs at 4MHz. To change it to 8MHz you must set `OSCCON`to `0x70` (bits 6-4 all '1').
2. Without a delay after changing the I/O pin's state it will toggle very fast (with an unequal up/down ratio). XC8 has built-in functions __delay_us() and __delay_ms() for creating long delays.

Here is your code modified to run the 12F683 at 8MHz with `GP0` toggling at 1Hz.

```
void main(void) {
  OSCCON = 0x70; // switch to 8MHz system clock
  GPIO = 0x00;
  ANSEL = 0x00;
  TRISIO = 0x00;
  ADCON0 = 0x00;
  CMCON0 = 7;
    while(1)
    {
        GP0 = 1;
        __delay_ms(500); // wait 500 milliseconds
        GP0 = 0;
        __delay_ms(500); // wait 500 milliseconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, that actually works. The problem is that I am a bit skeptical about my programmer (a cheap Chinese K150). Thank you for your answer.